# Remove the first word of a sentence

Tags: ruby

I am looking for a way to keep all the words of my sentence but the first one.
I made this in ruby :

```
    a = "toto titi tata"
    a.gsub(a.split[0]+' ','')
```

=> "tata titi"

Is there something better ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a regex.

```
a.gsub(/^\S­+\s+/, '');
```

Answer (score 2):

Lots of nice solutions here. I think this is a decent question. (even if it is a homework or job interview question, its still worth discussing)

## Here are my two approaches

```
a = "toto titi tata"    
# 1. split to array by space, then select from position 1 to the end
a.split
# gives you
  => ["toto", "titi", "tata"]
# and [1..-1] selects from 1 to the end to this will
a.split[1..-1].join(' ')

# 2. split by space, and drop the first n elements
a.split.drop(1).join(' ')
# at first I thought this was 'drop at position n'
#but its not, so both of these are essentially the same, but the drop might read cleaner
```

At first glance it might seem that all of the solutions are basically the same, and only differ by syntax/readability, but you might go one way or the other if:

1. You have a really long string to deal with
2. You are asked to drop words at different positions
3. You are asked to move words from one position to another

Comment: the drop is faster, but sub is the fastest solution for now.

Answer (score 1):

```
str = "toto titi tata"
p str[str.index(' ')+1 .. -1] #=> "titi tata"
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `gsub`, the `slice!` method will remove the part specified.

```
a = 'toto titi tata'
a.slice! /^\S+\s+/ # => toto (removed)
puts a             # => titi tata
```